# Combine two time-series with different element of the datetime index in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `time-series` below. `df1` has an index in a `DateTime` format which includes **only date** without time. `df2` has a full datetime index, also in a `DateTime` format. In the full data, `df1` is much shorter than `df2` in terms of the number of rows.

As you can see, both datasets span from the 2nd to the 6th of April. df1, however, skips some dates, while in df2, all days are available. Note: in this example, only odd dates are skipped, but it is not the case in the full data.

**df1**

```
    value1
date            
2016-04-02  16
2016-04-04  76
2016-04-06  23
```

**df2**

```
    value2
DateTime    
2016-04-02 07:45:00 257.96
2016-04-02 07:50:00 317.58
2016-04-02 07:55:00 333.39
2016-04-03 08:15:00 449.96
2016-04-03 08:20:00 466.42
2016-04-03 08:25:00 498.56
2016-04-04 08:10:00 454.73
2016-04-04 08:15:00 472.45
2016-04-04 08:20:00 489.85
2016-04-05 07:30:00 169.54
2016-04-05 07:35:00 276.13
2016-04-05 07:40:00 293.70
2016-04-06 07:10:00 108.05
2016-04-06 07:15:00 179.21
2016-04-06 07:20:00 201.80
```

I want to combine the two datasets by index. df1 should controls which dates to be kept. The **expected** result is below.

```
    value2  value1
DateTime    
2016-04-02 07:45:00 257.96  16
2016-04-02 07:50:00 317.58  16
2016-04-02 07:55:00 333.39  16
2016-04-04 08:10:00 454.73  76
2016-04-04 08:15:00 472.45  76
2016-04-04 08:20:00 489.85  76
2016-04-06 07:10:00 108.05  23
2016-04-06 07:15:00 179.21  23
2016-04-06 07:20:00 201.80  23
```

This is my attempt.

```
result= pd.concat([df1, df1], axis=1, sort=True).dropna(how='all')
```

But the result is different to what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible create new helper column filled by datetimes without times with [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html):

```
df2['date'] = df2.index.normalize()
```

Or if dates use [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df2['date'] = df2.index.date
```

And then use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) with default inner join:

```
result= df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on='date')
print (result)
                     value1  value2       date
DateTime                                      
2016-04-02 07:45:00      16  257.96 2016-04-02
2016-04-02 07:50:00      16  317.58 2016-04-02
2016-04-02 07:55:00      16  333.39 2016-04-02
2016-04-04 08:10:00      76  454.73 2016-04-04
2016-04-04 08:15:00      76  472.45 2016-04-04
2016-04-04 08:20:00      76  489.85 2016-04-04
2016-04-06 07:10:00      23  108.05 2016-04-06
2016-04-06 07:15:00      23  179.21 2016-04-06
2016-04-06 07:20:00      23  201.80 2016-04-06
```

---

Or use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), but it merging by previous match values, so working same like above only if always match datetimes without times from `df2` with `date`s from `df1`:

```
result= pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (result)
                     value2  value1
DateTime                           
2016-04-02 07:45:00  257.96      16
2016-04-02 07:50:00  317.58      16
2016-04-02 07:55:00  333.39      16
2016-04-03 08:15:00  449.96      16
2016-04-03 08:20:00  466.42      16
2016-04-03 08:25:00  498.56      16
2016-04-04 08:10:00  454.73      76
2016-04-04 08:15:00  472.45      76
2016-04-04 08:20:00  489.85      76
2016-04-05 07:30:00  169.54      76
2016-04-05 07:35:00  276.13      76
2016-04-05 07:40:00  293.70      76
2016-04-06 07:10:00  108.05      23
2016-04-06 07:15:00  179.21      23
2016-04-06 07:20:00  201.80      23
```